# Cisco term server 2509 password reset

Tags: cisco, router

I have bought a Cisco access server 2509 from eBay. But unfortunately they didn't give me a password. I tried to follow the password recovery procedure.

I am using Mac. I connect to access console server and launch it is using Minicom.

When I powered off and then on and I hit Cntrl+A then F which shows sending break. But it didn't take me into ROMmon mode.

Any other way to reset? Any other break key?

I tried cmd +b it didn't work.

Comment: Hit BREAK once rommon is initialized.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. When you use mac try using Z-TERMINAL(command-b) or iterm2(ctrl+a and then ctrl+b) instead of minicom  to get into rommon mode.
2. Only use connection through console port because other ports like Aux are not active while booting therefore useless to send break through Aux.
3. use these settings for console 
          9600 baud rate

   ```
      No parity

      8 data bits

      1 stop bit

      No flow control
   ```
4. Send break within a few seconds after powering on the cisco

Comment: What version of iTerm2 supports this kind of terminal emulation?

Comment: 2.0 but I never used it .

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried using iterm2 with above settings. Ahain ctrl+a cntrl+b doesnt took this into rommon mode.

Comment: Use Z-term, my friend use it and break command is command-b